# How to check foreground Android app activity

Tags: android, automation, foreground

i'm currently setting up an automation on my Android device and i need to know which activity is currently in the foreground so i can include it in the automation as a trigger.
I'm looking for the app activity withing the whole package

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if an Android application is running in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667022/checking-if-an-android-application-is-running-in-the-background)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use Activity Manager.

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
Log.d("topActivity", "CURRENT Activity ::" + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName());
ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
componentInfo.getPackageName();
```

You will need the following permission on your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
```

Comment: How do i use that

Comment: like a step by step